# Parse BIND DNS configuration file by Java?

Tags: java, regex, dns, named

I am trying to parse the BIND configuration line by line but it doesn't work. Because the BIND use the structure of

**keyword1** key_name **{**

**keyword2** key_value  **;**

**};**

to store the configuration.

How to parse a ISC BIND DNS configuration file by Java?

Example:

```
logging {
  channel "default" {
     file "C:\named\etc\default.log" versions 5 size 5m;
     severity dynamic;
     print-time yes;
     print-severity yes;
     print-category yes;
  };

  channel "general" {
     severity dynamic;
     file "C:\named\etc\general.log" versions 5 size 5m;
     print-time yes;
     print-severity yes;
     print-category yes;
  };

 category "default" {
     "default";
 };
 category "general" {
     "general";
 };

};
```

Here is my code:

```
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.FileReader;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.StringTokenizer;
        import java.util.regex.Matcher;
        import java.util.regex.Pattern;

        public class ScannerTest {

            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

                FileReader file = new FileReader("C:/named.conf");

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
                String line;
                boolean isChannel = false;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    if (line.length() <= 0)
                        continue; // skip empty line
                    if (line.charAt(0) == '#' | line.charAt(0) == '/')
                        continue; // skip comment line

                    if (isChannel) {

                        String endChannel = "};"; // end of block
                        String regexEndChannel = endChannel;
                        Pattern patternEndChannel = Pattern.compile(regexEndChannel);
                        Matcher matcherEndChannel = patternEndChannel.matcher(line);

                        if (matcherEndChannel.find() == false) {

                            // get the file name
                            String fileKey = "file";
                            String regex = "\\b" + fileKey + "\\b";
                            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
                            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

                            while (matcher.find() == true) {

                                String fileName = null;
                                StringTokenizer channelToken = new StringTokenizer(line);
                                if (channelToken.hasMoreTokens())
                                    fileKey = channelToken.nextToken();
                                if (channelToken.hasMoreTokens())
                                    fileName = channelToken.nextToken();
                                // get the file name
                                System.out.println("file Name: " + fileName);

                            }

                            // get the severity name
                            String severityKey = "severity";
                            // don't know why boundary the word "severity" with the \b
                            // but it still match the word print-severity
                            String regexseverity = "\\b" + severityKey + "\\b";
                            Pattern patternseverity = Pattern.compile(regexseverity);
                            Matcher matcherseverity = patternseverity.matcher(line);

                            while (matcherseverity.find() == true) {

                                String severityName = null;
                                StringTokenizer channelToken = new StringTokenizer(line);
                                if (channelToken.hasMoreTokens())
                                    severityKey = channelToken.nextToken();
                                if (channelToken.hasMoreTokens())
                                    severityName = channelToken.nextToken();
                                // get the file name
                                System.out.println("severity Name: " + severityName);

                            }

                            // get the last things
                            // print-time no;
                            // print-severity yes;
                            // print-category yes;

                        } else {

                            isChannel = false;
                        }
                    }

                    String channelKey = "channel";
                    String regex = "\\b" + channelKey + "\\b";
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

                    while (matcher.find() == true) {

                        isChannel = true;
                        String channelName = null;
                        StringTokenizer channelToken = new StringTokenizer(line);
                        if (channelToken.hasMoreTokens())
                            channelKey = channelToken.nextToken();
                        if (channelToken.hasMoreTokens())
                            channelName = channelToken.nextToken();
                        // get the channel name
                        System.out.println("Channel Name: " + channelName);
                    }

                }

                br.close();

            }

        }
```

Comment: I see no Java code here.

Comment: Good, and the problem with it is what, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [dnsjava](http://www.dnsjava.org/) zone file parser and look into the `org.xbill.DNS.Master` class which should parse what you need

Comment: The focus is ISC-style configuration file, not DNS zone data file.